# Why repository should not return DTO

Tags: php, laravel, design-patterns

Read a lot of articles where people say that I should return Domain Model... But that will ruin the whole idea of my repository then.

I am using laravel Eloquent Models (that, if I am correct - Domain Models). I have repository, so in case I will decide to switch to Doctrine, I could just swap it all in a service provider. But if I will return an instance of Domain Model (in this case, Eloquent Model) that makes no sense. I need to return the same result from repository, and DTO seems just what I need...

Can someone explain me why am I wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## What is what

First off I'd like to give my interpretation of the terms you're using.

### DTO (Data transfer object)

- Typically a PHP class with public properties
- Only responsible for carrying data
- Does not does not validate the data
- Does not know about any implementation specific things (e.g. which ORM it's tied to)
- Usually used for passing data between parts of the application, without either part knowing about the implementation of the other

### Domain model

- Typically a PHP class with private properties
- Should only contain valid data
- Validates that any changes result in a valid state
- Does not know about any implementation specific things (e.g. which ORM it's tied to)

### Repository

- Is only responsible for storing and retrieving data
- Does know about it's implementation (e.g. which ORM it's tied to)
- Is not responsible for returning valid data

## What this means for your case

The answer really depends on how pure you'd like to think in terms of splitting responsibilities.

If you're talking to purists they'd say that Eloquent models are not DTOs and they are not domain models either. A repository will return an eloquent model, which will be mapped to a domain model. That domain model can then be modified or converted to a DTO, which can be used for reading data. In this case the responsibilities are separated at the cost of having more code.

If you're talking to pragmatists they'd say that Eloquent models are DTOs and domain models (and sometimes even repositories as well). As the eloquent models are responsible for storing data, retrieving data, modifying data and passing this data to other parts of the application.

In the end it's all about preference. You can go pure, you can go pragmatic, you can even pick something in between. It purely depends on how advanced a coder you are, how big the project is, how maintainable it should be, how quick changes have to be made etc.

## Tdlr

A repository can return a DTO or a domain model depending on how pure you're thinking in terms of separating responsibilities.

Comment: What you describe as Domain Model is technically just an Entity. Domain Model usually refers to a set of interconnected objects that make up the data and business behaviors of a Domain as a whole. Cf. https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/domainModel.html